# how to include the javascript files in html?

Tags: javascript, html, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN application. I constructed my directory structure just using the express "app name" command, and I've created a index.ejs file which all my front end javascript file but for some reason when I run the app, it returns 404 not found for the js files. What is the proper path that I need to use to properly include my app.js, loginController.js, mainController.js, and registerController.js to my index.ejs.

[image: This is my folder structure]

This is the index.ejs, and I included the js files on the bottom. Is my src path wrong?
    
    
    
        Ango

```
<body ng-app="secret">
    <div id="mainBar">
        <div id="mainBarWrapper">
            <div id="siteLogo">
                <img src="images/mimiLogo.png" alt="mimi"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul id="navBar">
                    <li><a ui-sref="main">Home</a></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>

<script src="../public/javascripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="../public/javascripts/mainController.js"></script>
<script src="../public/javascripts/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="../public/javascripts/registerController.js"></script>
```

This is the error I am getting.
[image]

Comment: That's usually not how a MEAN is structured out

Comment: Your angular views should be in the public foldwr

Comment: And also not ejs. That's the whole point of angular. Angular is basically the same as ejs  no point combining them.

Comment: Try to use `src="javascripts/registerController.js"` instead of `src="../public/javascripts/registerController.js"`. may it works.

Comment: @Manu so what should be in the views folder then? Sorry I am new to MEAN, I thought that all the .ejs files in the views folder will act as my angular views?

Comment: Nothing needs to be in your views folder except for error pages when your not in the angular app.

Comment: @NeelShah that works! Can you explain why that is the proper path, because base on my directory structure, don't I have to one 2 levels up? You post this as an answer so I can accept. Thanks

Comment: @shuang If you go into your app.js you will see express uses a static folder.

Comment: @Manu great! thanks this makes more sense

Comment: @shuang As node express use your public folder to run application, you don't need to include absolute path to your application instead relative path to your app static folder.

Comment: @NeelShah what Manu said from the comments above is correct then. I should include my views in the public folder. But now I am confused should I be using express's index.js route to render my initial view or should I be using angular router to create my view. the index.js contains this                                                                              router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
}); which is what I though creates the first view. That is why I put all the ejs stuff in the views folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see your image is being loaded. But your scripts are not. You need to remove the `../public/` part of your url to be  just `javascript/index.js`

This is from expresses static folder public.

Answer (score 1):

Make your public folder static in your node server

`app.use(express.static('public'));`

or

put a route for your file.